# Sending a command using Ansible in Mongo DB CLI

Tags: mongodb, ansible

I am setting up an ansible script for health check purposes.

I want to run the `rs.status()` command after logging into mongo db admin cli.

```
---
- name: Perform Health Checks.
  hosts: mongodb
  tasks:
    - name: Check MongoDB nodes.
      shell: mongo admin -u root -p root ; rs.status()
      register: output

    - debug: msg={{ output.stdout_lines }}
```

The command `rs.status()` can only be run once Im in the mongodb admin console.

But running the above playbook using `shell` module gives me an ERROR.

```
TASK [Check MongoDB nodes.] **************************************************
fatal: [172.29.219.107]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "mongo admin -u root -p root ; rs.status()", "delta": "0:00:00.002825", "end": "2017-03-27 13:26:45.211397", "failed": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2017-03-27 13:26:45.208572", "stderr": "/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
fatal: [172.29.219.106]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "mongo admin -u root -p root ; rs.status()", "delta": "0:00:00.002906", "end": "2017-03-27 13:26:47.486562", "failed": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2017-03-27 13:26:47.483656", "stderr": "/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
```

Is there a way using Ansible that I can send the `rs.status()` command once Ive logged into mongodb console ?

Answer (score 4):

You can run `rs.status()` using `--eval` command line argument:

```
- name: Check MongoDB nodes.
  shell: mongo admin --quiet --eval 'printjson(rs.status())'
  register: output
```

`-u user`  and `-p pwd` command line arguments can be added to the command line if needed.